# How to do ANCOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a plot of samples versus an number [image]

the red dots have been modelled with a red regression line and the blue dots with a blue regression line. I would like to compare the two regression slopes to see if they are significantly different. I believe this is done with an ANCOVA. Does anyone know how to implement this in R?

The data to perform the graph is as follows:

```
structure(list(code = structure(c(25L, 37L, 13L, 
29L, 17L, 10L, 24L, 20L, 38L, 35L, 32L, 28L, 26L, 39L, 21L, 15L, 
31L, 9L, 16L, 23L, 7L, 18L, 42L, 34L, 4L, 33L, 19L, 22L, 27L), .Label = c("LP6005500-DNA_D01", 
"LP6005334-DNA_E02", "LP6005334-DNA_G03", "LP6007427-DNA_A01", 
"LP6005935-DNA_C03", "LP2000104-DNA_A01", "LP6005690-DNA_D01", 
"LP6005409-DNA_C02", "LP6005500-DNA_D03", "LP6005334-DNA_D03", 
"LP6005334-DNA_D01", "LP6007514-DNA_A01", "LP6005334-DNA_B02", 
"LP6005334-DNA_F03", "LP6005500-DNA_B01", "LP6005500-DNA_E01", 
"LP6005334-DNA_C03", "LP6005690-DNA_H01", "LP6007538-DNA_A01", 
"LP6005334-DNA_E03", "LP6005500-DNA_A01", "LP6007540-DNA_A01", 
"LP6005500-DNA_F01", "LP6005334-DNA_E01", "LP6005334-DNA_A02", 
"LP6005409-DNA_A03", "LP6007542-DNA_A01", "LP6005334-DNA_H03", 
"LP6005334-DNA_C02", "LP6007409-DNA_A01", "LP6005500-DNA_C01", 
"LP6005334-DNA_H01", "LP6007512-DNA_A01", "LP6007424-DNA_A01", 
"LP6005334-DNA_G02", "LP6005334-DNA_C01", "LP6005334-DNA_A03", 
"LP6005334-DNA_F01", "LP6005409-DNA_C04", "LP6005334-DNA_D02", 
"LP6007418-DNA_A02", "LP6007396-DNA_A01", "LP6005334-DNA_F02"
), class = "factor"), freq = c(503, 597, 354, 522, 399, 338, 
498, 430, 606, 590, 561, 518, 508, 618, 436, 373, 559, 328, 382, 
491, 313, 408, 683, 585, 261, 570, 423, 477, 515), CNI = c(21L, 
54L, 25L, 32L, 19L, 23L, 21L, 18L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 27L, 37L, 49L, 
26L, 11L, 11L, 24L, 13L, 31L, 19L, 21L, 28L, 32L, 17L, 44L, 22L, 
20L, 15L)), .Names = c("code", "freq", "CNI"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 
41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code for the graph

```
ggplot(FeqAndASCATmergeCell) +
  geom_bar(aes(code,Cellul*100),stat="identity")+
  geom_point(aes(code,freq),colour="blue")+
  geom_smooth(aes(code,freq,group=2),fill = "blue",alpha=0.2)+
  geom_point(aes(code,CNI*20),colour="red",size=5)+
  geom_smooth(aes(code,CNI*20,group=2),fill = "red", colour="red", alpha=0.2)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.7, 0.7))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(25, 50,75, 100,300,600,900))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text( size=10)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18,lineheight=.8, face="bold",vjust=1))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, size=10))
```

Comment: I do not even understand the plot. You have a categorical variable on the x-axis. How can you create a model predicting in between its (discrete) values? What does "between" even mean for a categorical variable?

Comment: OK. Basically I think I want to compare the slopes of the two lines.

Comment: Well, give us how these lines were calculated. As I said, they don't make sense. (And the red line doesn't have a constant slope.)

Comment: I've added the code for the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the slopes of a regression line with an ANCOVA, but **only** for straight lines, so with a constant slope. Because you didn't supply a method to `geom_smooth`, it uses `loess` and your lines don't have a constant slope. You can for example use `method = lm`:

```
ggplot(FeqAndASCATmergeCell) +
  geom_point(aes(code,freq),colour="blue")+
  geom_smooth(aes(code,freq,group=2),fill = "blue",alpha=0.2, method="lm")+
  geom_point(aes(code,CNI*20),colour="red",size=5)+
  geom_smooth(aes(code,CNI*20,group=2),fill = "red", colour="red", alpha=0.2, method="lm")+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.7, 0.7))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(25, 50,75, 100,300,600,900))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text( size=10)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18,lineheight=.8, face="bold",vjust=1))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, size=10))
```

This will give you straight lines:
[image]

Next, you can use an ANCOVA to test if these lines are different. Basically you test if the slope or intercept of the lines significantly differ. How you do that would make too long of an answer, but see [here](http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.nl/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html) for an R-example.